# Angular ng-repeat only showing the first item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, api

I have the following table:

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>ID</b></td>
                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Surname</b></td>
                    <td><b>House</b></td>
                    <td><b>Address</b></td>
                    <td><b>Locality</b></td>
                    <td><b>Contact1</b></td>
                    <td><b>Contact2</b></td>
                    <td><b>Contact3</b></td>
                    <td><b>Reply</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="telesale in telesales">
                    <td>{{telesale.ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Surname}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.House}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Address}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Locality}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Contact1}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Contact2}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Contact3}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Reply}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Angular:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

          GetPersons();

          function GetPersons() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/data'
            }).
            success(function (data) {
                if(data != null || data != 'undefined') {
                    $scope.telesales = data;
            }
          })
          .error(function (error) {
             $window.alert("Unable to retrieve people" + error.message);
          });
          }

      } ]);
  </script>
```

The data being retrieved from the api is a list with a count of 40 rows (made a breakpoint to verify), however only the row from the list is being displayed. Why could this be happening?

Comment: i don't understand the reason why do you have a dangling function in a controller. Why not create $scope.GetPersons and then call it before ending $scope.GetPersons().. May be that is what preventing you from acheiving the desired output.. ??

Answer (score 0):

That maight happend when your webapi controller return HttpResponseMessage message instead of pure data, in that case to get data you have to use `result.data` ie:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

          GetPersons();

          function GetPersons() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/data'
            }).
            success(function (result) {
                if(result.data != null || result.data != 'undefined') {
                    $scope.telesales = result.data;
            }
          })
          .error(function (error) {
             $window.alert("Unable to retrieve people" + error.message);
          });
          }

      } ]);
  </script>
```

Comment: You should write some description of your code. How could we understand it?

Comment: @ebramtharwat thanks for your feedback, was pretty busy but now I've updated my answer.

Comment: @sylwester the api returns an IEnumerable list. I tried like you suggested but then nothing is displayed

Comment: @rikket please see here http://jsbin.com/fihaje/1/edit?js just add console.log and let me know what you get on your console

Comment: @slywester the other rows are being displayed but the <td> in the rows are empty

Comment: @rikket can you please paste into jsbin your data from api call, it will be easier to help

Comment: @sylwester how can I post it in jsbin if data is being retrieved from the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58887/discussion-between-sylwester-and-rikket).

Comment: @sylwester sorry for not responsiding yesterday. I tried to pass the list as json too but still the same. very weird

Comment: @rikket more likely the problem is in serializing your CommonLayer.Telesales to json. Try to simplifya bit this object for start